# Reading Specific Python list from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently Trying to read all data Occurring after a colon ':' in a file for example.
In a text file containing only:

> SAM Account Type : 805306368

```
with open("Sample.txt") as myfile:
for line in myfile:
        flag=0
        if ("SAM Account Type" in line):
            for ch in line:
                if (flag and ch!=' ' and ch!='\n'):
                    B+=ch
                elif (ch == ':'):
                    flag+=1
                    S1 = myfile.read(10)
                   # print (ch)
                elif (ch=='\n'):
                    flag =0
                else:
                    pass
            print (B)
```

This works like a charm only showing me "805306368"
But when I try to check for more variable other than "SAM Account Type" by using a list it fails to give the correct output.

For example the file below:

> SAM Account Name : Ramachandran. S
>
> SAM Account Type : 805306368
>
> Description :
>
> User Account Control : 544
>
> When Created:09/21/2015 06:33:53
>
> Lastlogontimestamp : 130966421275783509
>
> When Changed :  01/07/2016 12:08:47
>
> Account Expires : 922337203685477580
>
> Last logoff :   00:00:00.0000000
>
> Last logon : 130971364125825724

and this following code :

```
A = []
A.extend({"SAM Account Type",
"User Account Control",
"Last logon",
"Lastlogontimestamp",
"Last logoff",
"Account Expires"})
B = ""

with open("Sample.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:


        for i in range(len(A)):
            flag=0
            if (str(A[i]) in line):
            #if ("SAM Account Type" in line):
                for ch in line:
                    if (flag and ch!=' ' and ch!='\n'):
                        B+=ch
                    elif (ch == ':'):
                        flag+=1
                        S1 = myfile.read(10)

                    elif (ch=='\n'):
                        flag =0
                    else:
                        pass
                print (B)
                B=""
```

Which Reads all the Characters after a ':' which Belong to an Entity in the list 'A' Stores them in 'B', and prints B for each line.

Gives The following:

> '805306368'
>   '544'
>   '130966421275783509'
>   '922337203685477580'
>   '130971364125825724'

When it should also give for 'Last logoff' which is '00:00:00.0000000'
But it doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if it is more or less efficient but it might be simpler to just initially read all lines, dump them in an array and then treat them without having to be carefull about file I/O syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are scanning for specific strings (ie those in A) I would create a list of each line in your file.

Split each line by `' : '` which seems to be the standard break between your key and your values in your txt file.

You now have a list that you can scan `B` and compare the first element of this list to the contents of `A`.  We can print the second element (what appears after `' : '` for each match:

```
B=[]

with open("Sample.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    B.append(line.split(' : ') 
for i in B:
  if i[0] in A:
    print i[1].strip()  #this removes the \n
```

Another 'fun' way to do this would be to create a dictionary

```
c={}
with open("Sample.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
   t=line.split(' : ')
   c.update({t[0]:t[1].split()})
for i in set(c.keys()) & set(A):  #gives set of matches between keys and A
  print c[1]
```

If you're into the whole brevity thing:

```
for i in open("Sample.txt").readlines():
  if i[:i.index(' : ')] in A:
    print i[i.index(' : ')+3:].split()[0]
```

Lastly:

```
print ''.join([i[i.index(' : ')+3:] for i in open("Sample.txt").readlines() if i[:i.index(' : ')] in A])
```

Comment: I see you are using Python 2.7.x .Not a problem. Thank you so much, It worked like a charm. I would still like to know what went wrong with my logic though,(if you have the time) lets assume the output isn't bugged by '\0'

Comment: @XChikuX your Python seems to work fine on for me (2.7) if I remove "S1 = myfile.read(10)"  I wasn't sure why this was in there, left over from first attempt?  S1 isn't referenced anywhere else

Comment: Ya, This code is part of something bigger that I was working on. 'S1' was just me trying to check a specific behaviour. 
Do you get the "Last Logoff" term as well?? In my output I never got '00:00:00.00000000' . You are supposed to get 6 output lines. But I kept getting only 5. If i re-arrange the file contents itself. I get the same 5 lines of output, but instead of "Last Logoff" someother parameter seems to be not taken.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can read all lines and process them as per your requirement. You can split a sentence based on ":" and use tokens.

*Note: As time also has : in it, you may want to use " : " (colon with 2 spaces)*

sample code:

```
In [1]: with open("./input.txt") as f: 
   ...:     data = f.readlines()
   ...:     


In [2]: data = [d for d in data if d!='\n'] #Drop empty lines

In [3]: data = [d[:-1].split(" : ") for d in data] # exclude \n (last char in the line) and split based on colon

In [4]: data
Out[4]: 
[['SAM Account Name', 'Ramachandran. S'],
 ['SAM Account Type', '805306368'],
 ['Description :'],
 ['User Account Control', '544'],
 ['When Created:09/21/2015 06:33:53'],
 ['Lastlogontimestamp', '130966421275783509'],
 ['When Changed', '01/07/2016 12:08:47'],
 ['Account Expires', '922337203685477580'],
 ['Last logoff', '00:00:00.0000000'],
 ['Last logon', '130971364125825724']]
```

Further,

1. You can convert this to dict using the key and value pair you got from processing. Later you can dump this dict to json for other tasks.
2. It seems like you are coming to python from C like language. In python, most of the things are inbuilt like reading a file, splitting a string, etc. So, refer to some tutorials like https://developers.google.com/edu/python/ , etc. to learn more

Comment: *being pedantic: if the last line of the text does not have a carriage return, or '\n' you will lose the last digit when you perform d[:-1]

Comment: @EoinS: True. we can use strip()  to make it better.

Comment: @Gurupad Thank You , and  I do come from a C++ background.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is print values to the right of the first colon if they have a string in A, then you could:

```
for line in myfile:
    split_line = line.split(' : ', 1) #splits into list of two elements at first colon unless colon is not found, then a list of one element
    if split_line[0] in A and len(split_line)==2:
        print split_line[1].replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: Smart using replace, I was doing split().[] for some odd reason, I'll update mine now with .replace('\n'), thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Does that answer the question?  Or is something still unclear?

Comment: @northsideknight Yes, I got it working. Thank you for your time.